# How to find the best combination of parameters from a very large sets?

Tags: algorithm

I have a processing logic which has **11 parameters**(let's say from parameter ***A*** to parameter ***K***) and different combinations of theses parameters can results in different outcomes.

```
Processing Logic Example:

if x > A:
    x = B
else:
    x = C

y = math.sin(2x*x+1.1416)-D

# other logic involving parameter E,F,G,H,I,J,K

return outcome
```

Here are some examples of the possible values of the parameters(others are similar, discrete):

```
A ∈ [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ..., 0.2]
E ∈ [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 200]
```

**I would like to** find the combination of these parameters that results in the best outcome.

However, **the problem I am facing** is that there are in total
10^19 possible combinations while each combination takes 700ms processing time per CPU core. Obviously, the time to process the whole combinations is unacceptable even I have a large computing cluster.

Could anyone give some advice on **what is the correct methodology** to handle this problem?

---

Here is some of my thoughts:

**Step 1**. Minimize the step interval of each parameter that reduces the total processing time to an acceptable scope, for example:

```
A ∈ [0.01, 0.05, 0.09, ..., 0.2]
E ∈ [1, 5, 10, 15, ..., 200]
```

**Step 2**. Starting from the best combination resulted from *step 1*, doing a more meticulous research around that combination to find the best combination

But I am afraid that the best combination might hide somewhere that *step 1* is not able to perceive, so *step 2* is in vain

Comment: Are you using Python? A compiled language might be significantly faster.

Comment: With all due respect @MarkSetchell and having my partial agreement on relative advantage of not relying on a slowly interpreted implementation language ( which OTOH per-se was **not** either explicitly *mentioned* or *implied* in rather abstractly formulated problem ), **using any kind of compiled language does not save any attempt to solve an ill-formulated problem** ( incomplete per-se or having some missing inital / boundary / behaviour properties defined ) **or an in-deterministic problem** Hope you would not mind mentioning these observations of an unbiased external observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an *optimization* problem.  However, you have two distinct problems in what you posed:

- There are no restrictions or properties on the evaluation function;
- You accept only the best solution of 10^19 possibilities.

The field of optimization serves up many possibilities, most of which are one variation or another of hill-climbing search and irruptive movement (to help break out of a local maximum that is not the global solution).  All of these depend on some manner of continuity or predictability in the evaluation function's dependence on its inputs.

Without that continuity, there is no shorter path to the sole optimal solution.

If you do have some predictability, then you have some reading to do on various solution methods.  Start with Newton-Raphson, move on to Gradient Descent, and continue to other topics, depending on the fabric of your function.

Comment: With all due respect to your insights, you have forgotten to mention **a third assumption :** *that a such 11-Dimensional **system has a non-evolving nature** ( i.e. a static state-space in time )*

Comment: The way I read this, any such evolution would be an additional variable in the problem, beyond what OP posed.

Comment: Well,not exactly, @Prune.A single extending dimension(add time)does not solve problems with any "hidden" dimension(s),the less systems,that are principally in-deterministic.If being methodically(as explicitly was requested by OP)accurate,the step-wise approach,the O/P has sketched above,does not say anything that may lead to your claimed defense of no need to go "beyond what OP posed". Hope we all can agree that **True Mathematics is a beautiful domain of proving facts,not a space for opinions.** Your advice has some engineering tips,yet it creates a false illusion of being a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about purely mathematical approach i.e. trying to find local/global extrema, or based on whether function is monotonic per operation?

There are quite decent numerical methods for derivatives/integrals, even to be used in a relatively-generic manner.

So in other words limit the scope, instead of computing every single option - depends on the general character of operations, that you have in mind.